# SELENIUM cant select javascript generated name

Tags: python, html, selenium

Hi this is the HTML I´m trying to insert the key in:

```
<input type="text" name="input[220].pk[202].name['CODICE_ORDINE_OLO'].value" alias="" value="" pattern=".*" class="form-control form-control-sm   null" maxlength="4000" data-placement="right" data-original-title="" title="">
```

The class is used in other parts of the HTML so i can´t use it to find it, the only unique thing is the name, but using xpath:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='input[220].pk[202].name['CODICE_ORDINE_OLO'].value']").send:keys(NW)
```

I get the following error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpa
th expression //input[@name='input[220].pk[202].name['CODICE_ORDINE_OLO'].value'] because of the following error:
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//input[@name='input[220].pk[202].name['CODICE_ORDI
NE_OLO'].value']' is not a valid XPath expression.
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the name is dynamic I would suggest to use `contains`

```
//input[contains(@name,"input[220]")]
```

If the name is static the please use the below `xPath`

```
//input[@name="input[220].pk[202].name['CODICE_ORDINE_OLO'].value"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you actually need to define string inside string inside string.
To do so you have to alter between `'` and `"` each time.
The entire XPath expression here is inside the single apostrophes `'` at the beginning and at the end, the `name` attribute value is quoted with double apostrophes `"` and the internal value `CODICE_ORDINE_OLO` is quoted with single apostrophes `'` again.
Try this:

```py
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@name="input[220].pk[202].name[' + 'CODICE_ORDINE_OLO' + '].value"]').send:keys(NW)
```